# Google Drive API: unsuccessful in updating the filename

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm uploading a file to Drive and then trying to update the filename using the id. This is what I'm doing:

```
    const updateFileName = await axios.patch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?updloadType=media`, 
        {'name':'MyFile.docx'},
        {headers: 
            {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${some_value}`,
            },                        
        },)
```

The problem is, instead of updating the filename, it updates the content of the file and replaces the content with `{'name':'MyFile.docx'}`. I can't figure out why it's replacing the actual content instead of the filename. The Drive v3 API for updating requires a name/originalName property in the request body, I tried with both. I've also tried replacing `name` with `title`. In all cases it overwrites the actual content in the file instead of changing the filename. Can someone please give me an idea about the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `?updloadType=media` which is telling Google you want to update the media content. Lose that bit, and you're off to the races. `Content Type` can probably be removed, but if you specify it, it should be `application/json`

and the URL should be `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId`

Comment: I removed the uploadType query param and then tried with this: 

        ```await axios.patch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${fileId}`, 
            {'name':'myFile.docx'},
            {headers: 
                {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${some_value}`,
                },                        
            },)```

It still updates the file content. Any idea why it's still the same issue?

Comment: ... and you-re using the wrong URL. see edited answer

Comment: that fixed it. Thanks a lot!